# How can I convert my encryption function so that the receiver can decrypt on the receivers side

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted message that my app sends on the receiver's side but it won't work...
most because I cannot access the encrypted message from the gmail iframe...

```
/*Registration of events for Chrome*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){


  Log("DOMContentLoaded");

  if(CryptoJS===null){
    Log("CryptoJS is null!!!!");
    return;

  }if (!formIsValid()){
    Log("Form invalid!!!!");
    return;

  }


  function getOptions()
{
    var mode;
    var padding;
    var selMode = document.getElementById("selMode").value;
    var selPad = document.getElementById("selPad").value;

    // mode
    if (selMode == "CBC"){
        mode = CryptoJS.mode.CBC;
    }
}

  //generate passphrase

   var passphrase=document.getElementById("passphrase").value;

   var cmdPassphrase=document.getElementById("passphrase");
   cmdPassphrase.addEventListener("click",

   function(){
     genPassphrase();

   },false);

   //encrypt button
    var cmdEncrypt = document.getElementById("cmdEncrypt");
    cmdEncrypt.addEventListener("click", 
        function() {
        cmdEncryptClick();
    }, false);

    //decrypt button
        var cmdVerify = document.getElementById("Decrypt");
    cmdVerify.addEventListener("click", 
        function() {
        cmdDecryptClick();
    }, false);

  //ciphertext text area
  var txtCiphertext = document.getElementById("txtCiphertext");
    txtCiphertext.addEventListener("click", 
        function() {
            cmdVerifySelectAll();
    }, false);


//padding function
function pbkdf2(passphrase, selKeySize, _salt)
{
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(selKeySize/8);
    if (_salt) salt = _salt;
    var keySizeBits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { keySize: selKeySize/32 });
    //var keySizeBits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { keySize: selKeySize/32, iterations: 1000 });
    return keySizeBits.toString();
}

//genPassphrase function

function genPassphrase()
{
    var selKeySize = document.getElementById("selKeySize");
    var passphrase = document.getElementById("passphrase");

    passphrase.value = pbkdf2("Secret Passphrase", selKeySize.value);
}

//left here at 6.12pm thursday 14th april*****
function cmdEncryptClick()
{
    var objPlaintext = document.getElementById("compose-message");
    var objCiphertext = document.getElementById("txtCiphertext");
    var selFunction = document.getElementById("selFunction");
    var selKeySize = document.getElementById("selKeySize");
    var passphrase = document.getElementById("passphrase");
    var selHash = document.getElementById("selHash");
    var selHashKeySize = document.getElementById("selHashKeySize");

    try
    {

        var plaintext = objPlaintext.value.trim();
        var ciphertext;

        /*** encrypt */
        if (selFunction.value == "AES")
        {
            var options = getOptions();  
            var key = pbkdf2(passphrase.value, selKeySize.value, "Secret Salt");

            var json = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, options);  
            //ciphertext = json.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            ciphertext = json.toString();
        }
        else if (selFunction.value == "HASH" && selHash.value == "SHA-1")
        {
            ciphertext = CryptoJS.SHA1(plaintext);
        }

        objCiphertext.value = ciphertext;

}
catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }

}
 function cmdVerifyClick ()
{
    var objCiphertext = document.getElementById("txtCiphertext");
    var objVerification = document.getElementById("txtVerification");
    var selKeySize = document.getElementById("selKeySize");
    var passphrase = document.getElementById("passphrase");

    try
    {

        var ciphertext = objCiphertext.value.trim();
        Log(ciphertext);
        var plaintext;


        /*** decrypt */
        if (selFunction.value == "AES")
        {
            var options = getOptions(); 
            var key = pbkdf2(passphrase.value, selKeySize.value, "Secret Salt");

            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, options);
            plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        }
                    objVerification.value = plaintext;
                    console.log(plaintext)

    }
        catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }

}




function selFunctionChange(method)
{
    var selFunction = document.getElementById("selFunction");
    var selHash = document.getElementById("selHash");
    var selHashKeySize = document.getElementById("selHashKeySize");
    if (!method) method = selFunction.value;

    var divFunction = document.getElementById("divFunction");
    var divHashFunction = document.getElementById("divHashFunction");
    var divCiphertext = document.getElementById("divCiphertext");
    var labelCiphertext = document.getElementById("labelCiphertext");
    var divVerification = document.getElementById("divVerification");
    var divVerify = document.getElementById("divVerify");
    var divPassphrase = document.getElementById("divPassphrase");

    var obj_ciph = document.getElementById("txtCiphertext");
    var obj_ver = document.getElementById("txtVerification");
    obj_ciph.value = "1";
    obj_ver.value = "2";

    if (method == "AES" || method == "RSA")
    {
        labelCiphertext.innerHTML = "Ciphertext";
        divFunction.style.display = "block";
        divHashFunction.style.display = "none";
        //divCiphertext.style.display = "block";
        divVerification.style.display = "block";
        divVerify.style.display = "block";
        divPassphrase.style.display = "block";
    }
    else if (method == "HASH")
    {
        labelCiphertext.innerHTML = "Digest";
        divFunction.style.display = "none";
        divPassphrase.style.display = "none";
        divHashFunction.style.display = "block";
        //divCiphertext.style.display = "none";
        divVerification.style.display = "none";
        divVerify.style.display = "none";

        if (selHash.value == "MD5" || selHash.value == "SHA-1")
            selHashKeySize.disabled = true;
        else selHashKeySize.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        labelCiphertext.innerHTML = "Ciphertext";
        divFunction.style.display = "none";
        divHashFunction.style.display = "none";
        divVerification.style.display = "block";
        divVerify.style.display = "block";
        divPassphrase.style.display = "block";
    }

}






function cmdResetFormClick()
{
    document.getElementById("txtCiphertext").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txtVerification").value = "";
}


function formIsValid()
{
    var obj_plain = document.getElementById("compose-message");
    var obj_ciph = document.getElementById("txtCiphertext");
    var selFunction = document.getElementById("selFunction");
    var selHash = document.getElementById("selHash");
    var selHashKeySize = document.getElementById("selHashKeySize");

    if (selFunction!=null && selHash!=null && selHashKeySize!=null 
     && obj_plain!=null && obj_ciph!=null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

function Log(x)
{
    Common.log(x);
    var txtMessages = document.getElementById("txtMessages");
    if (txtMessages!=null)
    {
        txtMessages.value = x;
    }
}
});
```

a brief description of the app im going to use the gmail api to send encrypted messages....thus encryption is not a problem but decrypting the message on the receiver's side is....
I need help to exhange the passphrase and to modify my decryption function.

Comment: are you using CryptoJS right?

Comment: yes im using CryptoJS@Matheus Silva

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291279/how-to-convert-to-string-and-back-again-with-cryptojs it might help. To decrypt the message just using the same library to decrypt, otherwise the user wont be able to do it.

Comment: okay Thankx let me try